# Enable CTRL shortcuts in Windows Terminal for Powershell

Tags: windows-terminal

I am trying to enable CTRL shortcuts in Windows Terminal as per my current powershell instance but cannot figure out for life of me how to go about it.

Any advice ideas?

Comment: 1 - This should be moved to SuperUser 2 - This is a known issue/bug: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/879 https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2865